# Highlight tableview cell when tapped and unhighlight when alert controller action buttons are pressed

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiactionsheet

I like to highlight row in tableview cell when user touches the cell in `blue`, and then when user selects the action button, I want it to change it to `gray` color

```
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    var newCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)!
    newCell.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue

    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

    let okButton = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: { (action) -> Void in
        print("Ok button tapped")
        var newCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)!
        newCell.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
    })

    let cancelButton = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: { (action) -> Void in
        print("Cancel button tapped")
        var newCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)!
        newCell.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
    })

    alertController.addAction(okButton)
    alertController.addAction(cancelButton)

    present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didhighlightRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    var newCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)!
    newCell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
}
```

I did this and it highlights the cell in `white` color and after action button is tapped, it still stays `white` but when I tap another cell, the previous cell turns and remains `gray`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In view controller initialization:

```
NSMutableSet *selectedRows = NSMutableSet.alloc.init;
NSIndexPath *lastSelected = nil;
```

In table view initialization:
`tableview.allowsMultipleSelection = false`

In did select row:
Fire alert (you already have this), `lastSelected = indexPath;`, `[selectedRows addObject:indexPath.row]`.

In cell for row:
`cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewSelectionStyleBlue;`

```
if ([selectionSet contains:indexPath.row])
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor;
else
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor;
```

In alert view delegate:
`[tableview deselectRowAtIndexPath:selectedIndexPath]` and `[tableview reloadIndexPath:lastSelection]`

This should:
1) start with all cells clear

2) turn cell blue when clicked by default highlighting

3) redraw cell after alert view selection

4) cell will redraw with gray color if it is in the selectedRow set

Comment: 1. My cells are clear color 2. When user taps they turn blue 3. When user presses action button they turn gray and stay gray. I hope it is clear to you now. Sorry for confusion

Comment: I understand now :) my most recent edit should do the trick. The key is to reference the "was selected" state in cellForRow to determine background color.

Comment: Appreciate the response. Do you have any brief example code about the steps you were talking that will help me a lot.

Comment: I will ping you once I test this out

Comment: I hope you have success, i wrote this from my cell phone without a compiler or syntax checker :p my goal was to just provide you with an approach, coding on a touch screen is hard!

Comment: I like your effort, I am coding in swift, so I an now in process of translating it and testing it out

Comment: If the design and approach are sound, would you consider upvoting and accepting this answer? Thanks!